# What language are Android apps built in?

Tags: app-store

I have just started learning about Android and I was planning on making a few apps.

So I was wondering what language do I build apps on and what are the free tools and ebooks about it and also any good IDE for it?

Comment: As Edelcom says, this is meant for http://stackoverflow.com however if you search there first you should find a few useful questions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's in **Java** and the **IDE** that can be used is Eclipse:
[all information on this SDK page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

But you should ask this on the Stackexchange site: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+eclipse)

Comment: You can also build portions in C or C++ using the Android NDK: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: This answer is out of date, use Android Studio now.

Answer (score 4):

As Edelcom said, Android apps are built in Java.

Eclipse is one of the IDEs that can be used, though personally I prefer using [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). IntelliJ10 comes with Android SDK - go for the Community Edition, it's free :)

Have a look at the Android website for lots of information, the tutorials are a good place to start, and are great for hands-on learning - http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial

Answer (score 2):

As of December 2014 use Android Studio.